# Nested Image/Video Galleries in Drupal 7

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, files, media

Alright so after looking around for awhile and not finding exactly what I am looking for hopefully someone can help me out with this.

On my website I plan on having both image galleries and video galleries.
I can configure a views gallery or using Media Gallery which works wonders except for what I want to do(media gallery that is).

My videos (or even images if this is possible) section I would like to have nested galleries potentially up to 3 tiers at a time. I am assuming I can do this taxonomy but I don't want to add a new term every time a new 'series' comes out, as I don't necessarily know the name of said series before it comes out.

I would like my gallery to flow as such:

1. Galleries Overview

   - Gallery A

     - Gallery A1

       - Nested Gallery A11
       - Nested Gallery A12
       - Nested Gallery A13
     - Gallery A2

       - Nested Gallery A21
       - Nested Gallery A22
       - Nested Gallery A23
     - Gallery A3

       - Gallery A31
       - Gallery A32
       - Gallery A33
   - Gallery B

     - Gallery B1
     - Gallery B2
     - Gallery B3
   - Gallery C

     - Gallery C1
     - Gallery C2
     - Gallery C3

I am probably over thinking this and there must be an easier way to do this because I have read posts of sites with nested galleries I just cant seem to figure it out.

Final option would be to downgrade to Drupal 6. If it is truly easier this way, it is not that big of a deal, (no real content on my site yet). I know nested galleries are done on D6, and a few years back I had a D6 website with Nested Galleries which is why I am surprised this is an issue now.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is information architecture. I suggest you use the book module to define the hierarchy. This is an underestimated core module, which works amazingly well and has good integration with Drupal. In a recent site I've architected, all the site navigation was built dynamically using views, book-related contextual filters, and the viewfield module (which allows to put a view inside view). Play with the setup below and enjoy!

Detailed instructions:

1. Enable the book module.
2. Define top galleries as toplevel books, without a parent:

   - Go to the node editing screen.
   - Click on the new 'Outline' toplevel tab created by the book module.
   - Click on the 'Add to book outline' button. This will create a new book.
3. For each child gallery, select it's parent gallery

   - The parent gallery may be one of the toplevel galleries created on the previous steps, or one of the previous child galleries created on this step.
   - The child gallery may either be selected on the on the 'Outline' tab (when editing existing nodes) or on the 'Book Outline' vertical tab  displayed below (when creating new nodes).
     [image: 'Book outline']
4. Create a new view, which will show your toplevel galleies. let's call it "top galleries"

   - Open a 'block' display
   - Make the view field-based.
   - Add the title field to show the gallery title.
   - Add a viewfield to show the sub-galleries of this book.
   - The viewfield will refer to a new view we will create in the next step.
   - And, most imprtantly, use a filter criteria of Book: Depth (=1)
     [image: top galleries view]
5. Create a "gallery-inner" view.

   - Open the 'Advanced' setting
   - Create a relationship from the node to Book: Parent - the parent book node.
   - Set a contextual filter to "Content: Nid" taken from the parent book node.
   - Now the view show all children of it's parent book.
   - I haven't tried it but you may also try to add another viewfield here to show the children of those child views recursively, until there is a level with no more children (if it doesn't work, then create anorhter  "gallery-grandchildren" view for the 3rd level. Please report back here and write which way succeeds.
     [image: Inner gallery view]

Notes: 
- The screenshots were taken from a similar solution, where I've implemented all of the site navigation menus using the book hierarchy defined by the user. So please add an image field to each view where appropriate.

Comment: After taking some time and looking over this, this definitely seems like a very possible solution. Unfortunately I haven't had time to implement it yet, but as soon as I do I will share my results.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might take a look at a gallery I've made for the company I work for. http://www.vilavitaparcgallery.com. Bear in mind my goal is not to display photos (you can use any Gallery/lightbox module for that), but to allow our partners to download images in high-resolution.
While I found several problems in common with what you ask.

It's done in Drupal 7, using Views and taxonomies.

Basically, I created a Taxonomy Vocabulary that showcases the various categories and arranged them into a hierarquie. That hierarqy is then shown as a menu in a block with the **Taxonomy Menu module**.

I also use **Hierarchical Select  module**, to allow for a simple taxonomy selection while an administrative user is inserting new content. It's just a fancy way of tagging the categories.

Finally, on the front page I display a simple view that gets all photos with the selected Taxonomy, through the **Hierarchical Select Taxonomy Views** feature.

It turned out to work very well, and the organization feature ends up being highly flexible (its just managing tags) and very standard (it's just a view!). 
And this means I can use it in any layout, or theme without much fuss.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple galleries in one site like photos, videos, Presentations and e-books:
In my case I need 4 different galleries with 3 levels:
1) Level 1-> front page block for any albums new image
2) Level 2->Album page where there are lots of albums for ex: animals, plants etc
3) Level3->individual album items with their default content link
!st step
Create Taxonomy : create a taxonomy called “Album”
Add Vocabulary: add vocabularies
1) Photos
2) Videos
3) Presentations
4) E-books
Create Content type : we have to handle all galleries from only 1 album content type and album items content type
Add content types Album and Album type
Album Manage field Album Item Manage field
Title Title
Body Body
Album type: term ref(taxonomy: albums) Album type: term ref(taxonomy: albums)
Album Thumb: image Galleries: entity ref(ex Animals, Plants)
Comment: closed Album Thumb: image
Album Video: video embed
Comment: open

Install module: Node Gallery , its automatically create two new views in your views section after that just need to node gallery summaries 3 more times
Album Types Node views Summaries (customize it name when done ex: photos, videos, presentations, e-books)
Photos In fields add this:
Content : Album types: Photos
Videos In fields add this:
Content : Album types: Videos
Presentations In fields add this:
Content : Album types: Presentations
E-books In fields add this:
Content : Album types: E-books

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by just a content type, a block and views
1) add a content type with field of image and gallery group 
2) and than add a view with create a block and you can show your gallery on that block